# extracting numeric characters at end of string

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract a total $ amount from a string of imported characters in Google Sheets. The import (in column I) always looks something like this:

> Rack Cards (Amount: 22.00 USD, Quantity: 50) Trifolds (Amount: 49.00 USD, Quantity: 100) Postcard Magnets (Amount: 19.00 USD, Quantity: 20) Subtotal: 90.00 Tax: 7.20
>
> Total: 97.20

I'm using the formula =RIGHT(I2,(FIND(" ",I2)-1)) to return ONLY the total. In this particular case, I get the returned answer "97.20", which is correct.

HOWEVER, I also get a return of "l: 82.08" when the corresponding I column reads

> Stickers (Amount: 74.62 USD, Quantity: 50) Subtotal: 74.62 Tax: 7.46
>
> Total: 82.08

LIKEWISE, I get " 145.20" - including a space at the beginning - when the corresponding I column reads

> Flyers (Amount: 19.50 USD, Quantity: 25) Trifolds (Amount: 112.50
> USD, Quantity: 500) Subtotal: 132.00 Tax: 13.20
>
> Total: 145.20

This is driving me batty. I can't figure out why this formula would return characters after the space character, and it seems arbitrary. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `FIND(" ",I2)` will find the first space left to right not the first space right to left.

Comment: Use Regexextract

Comment: @JvdV I was unaware of Regextract - had to do a bit of research to figure out how to include decimals, but that worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your samples, try

```
=regexextract(index(split(A1,char(10)),1,2),"[0-9.]+")
```

I am using here a very simple extract expression as `[0-9.]+` on the second line